# How to set up a Java workspace without an IDE

Tags: java, jar, compilation, executable-jar, workspace

I usually code with IDEs like Intellij Idea or Eclipse, but due to several reasons, I no longer have access to an IDE, and I'd like to be able to code in Java on a remote Linux machine through a ssh terminal. 
Making simple progams with only a few classes is easy, but some of my projects have several libraries and several separate .java files. I also need to export to a .jar file.

For example, I have the following file organisation:

```
project/
   src/
      a.java
      b.java
      c.java
   libs/
      lib1.jar
      lib2.jar
   out/
      export_here.jar
   someconfig.conf
```

The java app consists of the a, b, and c .java files, uses libraries lib1 and lib2, and the file someconfig.conf needs to be inside the export jar.

**I want to know how to easily compile and build a project such as this.**

In other words, I just want to know how to export my project into a runnable jar the right way.

I expect this can be done with a few commands. If so, I plan to make a shell script to automate everything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not a web gui for your development? such as Codeenvy

Comment: Use a build system like Ant or Maven

Comment: It's long to explain here, but Maven can help you with this as you only need a way to organize your code, jars, dependencies, resources, etc.

Comment: @VeenarM I am using a web gui for this, but I have not yet found one that can automatically export complicated projects like this. I need to use the terminal.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have very little experience with Maven and none with Ant. Could you please explain how exactly I can set it up?

Comment: Then it's probably time to hit some tutorials.  Check out [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to start with, personally, it's easier to come to grips with then Maven, but Maven supplies dependency management as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I'll make sure to check it out if no one provides a good example.

Comment: The problem is, just about any answer you get would be a tutorial dump anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by other users you need to use a build management tool to do this like `Ant, Maven etc`. I have used Ant quiet frequently to do these kind of automated tasks. In order to **install and Use Ant** you can refer [How To Install Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)

After that the main task is to **write your automation script and that is called a build xml in ant world**. Here is a sample build.xml file you can refer to start with:

```
<project>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.HelloWorld"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

And for more information on the above sample [You can visit this](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

In General you can read more at [How to create build.xml](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)

After creating your build.xml you can run ant by `ant <path to build.xml>` or `ant` in case your build.xml lies in current directory

Hope this helps you in right direction

Comment: Glad that helped you. Have fun coding :)